# How can I resolve this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException that works on one computer but not on another?

Tags: java, windows-10, indexoutofboundsexception, windows-7-x64

So I'm at a loss on how to go about this.

I'm using Eclipse as my IDE and export a runnable jar through it. Everything's worked before except now that I have a ComboBox and load it with an array (FX.Collections-thing). I run it on my Windows 7 computer where I do my development, then I move it over to my Windows 10 computer where I test to make sure things run alright, but it isn't in this case.

OutOfBoundsException are usually simple to deal with, but I'm at a loss on how to deal with this exception since it works on one computer (there is no runtime exception) and in the other there's this exception(s):

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
at my.pages.giftcertmaker.MainGiftCertPage.start(MainGiftCertPage.java:52)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)
... 1 more
Exception running application my.pages.giftcertmaker.MainGiftCertPage
```

Edit: Forgive me for not doing my due diligence below are lines 51 and 52

```
ArrayList<Integer> certNumbersFound = workbook.getCertNumbers();
int lastNumber = certNumbersFound.get(certNumbersFound.size()-1);
```

Which begs the questions what's in getCertNumbers()

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getCertNumbers()
{
  ArrayList<Integer> numbersUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 /*
  * Code reads from an excel file column of doubles and converts
  * the doubles to ints and adds them to numbersUsed with a for-loop
  */
  return numbersUsed;
```

I've tried 4 different Java versions (1.8.0_181, _192, _201,_202). I've tried changing the double types read from the excel file at different parts of the code. I've tried changing the type of the ArrayList from , , and . I've changing the location of code loaded. It always goes to this part:

```
certNumbersFound.get(certNumbersFound.size()-1)
```

I always thought this was ok, but what is a better way? Or am I just unlucky? And I've also System.out.println-ed the ArrayList before the launch(args) method in the main and made certNumbersFound.size()-1 into it's own object before putting into the get method of the ArrayList.

And all the libraries have worked previously, but adding this ComboBox and the ArrayList (rather the FX.Collections-thing) ruins it.

I'm truly dumbfounded.

Comment: Are you sure Windows 10 supports the libraries you're using? Do you have same Java versions installed?

Comment: Maybe a code snippet could help.

Comment: `at my.pages.giftcertmaker.MainGiftCertPage.start(MainGiftCertPage.java:52)` what is written in that line? Show a [mcve].

Comment: Always start by reading the error message. It says: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`. Which means you're trying to access the element at index `-1`. The value of the index in your code is `certNumbersFound.size()-1`. Which means that `certNumbersFound` is an empty list: its size is 0. Where does this list come from? From `workbook.getCertNumbers();`. So this method, at this time, returns an empty list. Keep reasoning like I just did to find the root cause of the problem: we don't have the code necessary to do it.

Comment: My guess is that the file, on the machine, isn't there, or is empty, and the method thus returns an empty list. Use reasoning, and your debugger, to find out.

Comment: Where is the Excel file that you are reading? How do you specify its location? Do you use relative or absolute paths? What method are you using to read it?

Comment: @JBNizet This is why I'm so dumbfounded. I've done all the reasoning I could think of and no matter what. The code works fine on my Windows 7 computer, but doesn't on my Windows 10 computer. I've gone into the command prompt for each and launched the jar there with the Windows 10 computer being the only one that gives the error. 

The way the file is loaded into the ArrayList, there's no way it's not there because it checks for it's existence and if it's not there it creates a new file with the template it should have......and there's the issue! I'm so dumb. Thank you.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Relative? It uses the FileSystemView class to create/get the file from the Desktop. The only Absolute thing is the file name and extension type. I was using a couple of methods, but it'd be lengthy to explain, I think. JB Nizet helped me worked through it, so the issue is resolved. Sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to JB Nizet for helping me work through this one.

I had checks for if the file wasn't there, a new file would be created with the proper template as a redundancy. But! That didn't mean there were any values within the template to load the ArrayList.

The only reason why it worked on my Windows 7 computer (development computer) was because it had a test file with figures already in the template, so it had never ran from scratch like it was doing on my Windows 10 (testing computer).

I have to add a method or an if statement saying:

```
if(certNumbersFound != null && certNumbersFound.size() > 0)
{
  //Write code that can use the ArrayList certNumbersFound
  //because there's values in the file
}
else
{
  //Write code that doesn't use the ArrayList certNumbersFound
  //because there's no values in the file.
}
```

I feel so dumb. Thanks everyone. I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList.get` throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is out of range. In your case probably less than zero.

To avoid that add a check to your code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> certNumbersFound = workbook.getCertNumbers();
if (certNumbersFound.size() >= 1) {
    int lastNumber = certNumbersFound.get(certNumbersFound.size()-1);
    //more code
}
else {
    //handle situation according to your needs
    //e.g. throw exception, log something or write to err: 
    System.err.println("Invalid size: " + certNumbersFound.size());
}
```

When reading data from external sources (like an Excel file in this case) it is always a good idea to introduce safety checks.

An even better idea is to put exception handling (or: *expect the unexpected* handling code) inside `getCertNumbers` which is the method where you read a (potentially unreliable) external source. External source in this context means: not controlled by Java compiler.